# Play Quicktime movie from Terminal

Tags: macos, quicktime, automator

Is there a possibility to play a Quicktime movie (.mov) file from the command line (i.e., Terminal)?

I haven't found a way to achieve this. I could do it with an Automator script but it would be nicer if I can run it directly from the Terminal.

Comment: This kind of question I presume is welcome on apple.stackexchange.com, by the way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
open movie_file_name.mov
```

will open the default player from the terminal.

Comment: Is there also a way to auto play this file after opening?

Comment: It depends on the player: some could have a command line interface. Others can be set to automatically play files at startup. Anyway there is not a general way to achieve what you ask, at least not that I know..

Comment: Is there a way we could also specify the player ?

Answer (score 21):

```
open -a "quicktime player" movie_file_name.mov
```

You can specify other players, like VLC if you want:

```
open -a vlc movie_file_name.mov
```

Comment: Is there a way to play it minimized?